# How can I use LINQ / C# to return an object's nested list as a list in its own right with each item linked to the relevant original object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of object A and within this list is a property that is a list of object B.

For example:

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ObjectB> ObjectBs { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ObjectAId { get; set; }
    public ObjectA ObjectA { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a `List<ObjectA>` and each ObjectA contains its own list of ObjectB, is there anyway I can sort of pivot that so that I return a list of all the ObjectBs in ObjectA, each with its own ObjectA based on ObjectBs link to ObjectAs Id?

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: It's unclear to me whether the `ObjectB` instances already *have* the back-link in place or not. It's also unclear whether you want a single list returned, or a list of lists, or something else. Providing a complete example of input (setting up the data) and expected output (including the *type* of the output) would make this question a lot clearer.

Comment: LINQ deals with objects. Objects don't need IDs, databases do. `ObjectB` in the question already references `ObjectA` so the only code needed is `listA.SelectMany(a=>a.ObjectBs)`, assuming the objects were fully created. ORMs like EF Core will populate `ObjectB.ObjectA` if you use eager loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var flatList = listOfA.SelectMany(
        a => a.ObjectBs,
        (a, b) => { b.ObjectA = a; return b; }
    ).ToList();
```

This should give you a list of ObjectB with a reference to the coresponding ObjectA
That is what I think you ask

Answer (score 0):

```
objectAList.SelectMany(
    a => a.ObjectBs,
    (a,b) => new { Parent = a, Child = b});
```

should give you a sequence of objects with a `Parent` and `Child` property which refer to the `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` respectively.